# Select MySQL row where column is closest to current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with a bunch of rows. One of the columns is "date" which has a date for each row in the format: MM/DD/YYYY H:MM PM/AM

How can I write PHP that selects the row where the date is the most recent date that has passed. Meaning if you have a date of tomorrow, a date of today, and a date of yesterday, it picks the row where the date is of yesterday.

I've already connected to the database:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','username','pass');
mysql_select_db('db_name');
```

How do I write a query to grab this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If you want to keep using the mysql*_ functions, for the majority you can just change mysql to mysqli.  So use mysqli_connect() and mysqli_select_db() and soforth.  While this wasn't the intention for mysqli, it will work in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the filtering in SQL rather than PHP, using a variation of the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE theDate < CURDATE()
ORDER BY theDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This selects all the rows in the past (`theDate < CURDATE()`), sorts them in reverse chronological order (`ORDER BY theDate DESC`), then takes the first record (`LIMIT 1`).

Answer (score 0):

When you query the database, ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1

This will only return the most recent result, and thus the result that is closest to the current date. (This only works if you don't put entries that are dated in the future)